# EAccessViolation Error in application running Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, emulation

I've been using this certain application among previous windows versions (Windows XP-Vista-7-8-8.1) and it has worked perfectly without having any issues, after upgrading to Windows 10 though it started showing EAccessViolation error and spams the place with message boxes saying "Runtime error at XXXX" (memory address)

So what I've been trying to achieve is creating a program in C# which runs the application under all compatibility modes one by one, to check which one works and which one doesn't - and sadly, none of them did.

The application is not mine and has stopped development.

Do you guys have any idea what has changed in Windows 10 code-wise, and how am I able to fix this issue? Is there a way to fully emulate another windows version and run it for this application alone? (Without having to set up a Virtual PC or anything)

Thank you in advance.

Note: Microsoft said that Windows 10 is completely backwards compatible, which it doesn't seem like it? The application does not use any driver, it's just a standalone EXE coded in C++/Lua.

Note2: The EXE calls a DLL which might be outdated for Windows 10, any idea what to do about the DLL? Is there a way to make it work as it did in previous windows?

Answer (score -1):

You can help prevent these kinds of errors from occurring by updating your device drivers after formatting and reinstalling your operating system or installing a Windows Updates. Always install the latest Windows Updates before going through and updating your device drivers.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but my windows is fully updated with the latest updates.